# passing nested dict to a method failed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I ran the below code and compared `mrnas` in `write2gff` and `run` methods. It turns out that `mrnas` in the `run` method contain 1 list element. On the other hand, `mrnas` in the `write2gff` method contain 0 list element. Please see the print output from the below code:

```
NbV1Ch08 g63 1
Prepare to write!!!
NbV1Ch08 g63 0
```

How is it possible to fix that `mrnas` in the `write2gff` contain the same 1 element as `run` method?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import click
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
from BCBio import GFF
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio.SeqFeature import SeqFeature, FeatureLocation


class Gene():
    def __init__(self, type, start, end, strand, qualifiers):
        self.type = type
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.strand = strand
        self.qualifiers = qualifiers

def write2gff(genes, mrnas, ref_info):
    print("Prepare to write!!!")
    with open("data/test.gff3", "w") as out_keep:
        for seqID in genes.keys():
            rec = SeqRecord(Seq(ref_info[seqID] * 'A'), seqID)

            for gene_id in genes[seqID].keys():
                gene = genes[seqID][gene_id]
                top_feature = SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(gene.start, gene.end), type="gene",
                                         strand=gene.strand, qualifiers=gene.qualifiers)

                print(seqID, gene_id, len(mrnas[seqID][gene_id]))

                top_feature.sub_features = mrnas[seqID][gene_id]
                rec.features.append([top_feature])
            GFF.write([rec], out_keep)


@click.command()
@click.option('--gff3', help="Provide GFF3 file", required=True)
@click.option('--keep', help="Keep GFF3 file", required=True)
@click.option('--reject', help="Reject GFF3 file", required=True)
@click.option('--xml', help="Blast XML file", required=True)
@click.option('--fasta', help="Blast XML file", required=True)
def run(gff3, keep, reject, xml, fasta):
    ref_info = {i.id: len(i) for i in SeqIO.parse(fasta, "fasta")}
    #blast_hits = retrieve_hits_data(xml)
    test={}
    test["g63.t3"] = "B3 domain-containing protein Os03g0120900"
    genes = OrderedDict()
    mrnas = defaultdict()

    for rec in GFF.parse(gff3):
        for gene in rec.features:
            mrnas[rec.id] = defaultdict(list)
            for mrna in gene.sub_features:
                if mrna.id in test:
                    mrna.qualifiers["Note"] = test[mrna.id] #blast_hit.hit_def
                    mrnas[rec.id][gene.id].append(mrna)
                    print(rec.id, gene.id, len(mrnas[rec.id][gene.id]))


            if len(mrnas[rec.id][gene.id]) > 0:
                genes[rec.id] = defaultdict()

                genes[rec.id][gene.id] = Gene(gene.type, gene.location.start, gene.location.end,
                                              gene.location.strand, gene.qualifiers)

    write2gff(genes, mrnas, ref_info)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: You'd have a better chance to get an answer if you'd provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Maybe the line `mrnas[rec.id] = defaultdict(list)` overwrites your `mrnas` after the first print but before the second?  Outside of that I agree with Yevhen, I'm fairly certain you could recreate this issue with far fewer lines of code.

Comment: Thank you, I moved `mrnas[rec.id] = defaultdict(list)` and it works now.